# Verilog module generates impossible data when running on FPGA

Tags: verilog, zynq

I’m developing a boolean data logger on a ZYNQ 7000 SoC. The logger takes a boolean input from GPIO and logs the input’s value and the time it takes to flip.

I use a 32-bit register as a log entry, the MSB bit is the boolean value. The 30:0 bits is an unsigned integer which records the time between last 2 flips. The logger should work like the following picture.

[image: logger]

Here's my implementation of the logger in Verilog. To read the logged data from the processor, I use an AXI slave interface generated by vivado and inline my logger in the AXI module.

```
module BoolLogger_AXI #(
    parameter BufferDepth = 512
)(
    input wire data_in, // boolean input
    input wire S_AXI_ACLK, // clock
    input wire S_AXI_ARESETN, // reset_n
    // other AXI signals
);
wire slv_reg_wren; // write enable of AXI interface
reg[31:0] buff[0:BufferDepth-1];

reg[15:0] idx;
reg[31:0] count;
reg last_data;
always @(posedge S_AXI_ACLK) begin
    if((!S_AXI_ARESETN) || slv_reg_wren) begin
        idx <= 0;
        count <= 1;
        last_data <= data_in;
    end else begin
        if(last_data!=data_in) begin // add an entry only when input flips
            last_data <= data_in;
            if(idx < BufferDepth) begin // stop logging if buffer is full
                buff[idx] <= count | (data_in << 31);
                idx <= idx + 1;
            end
            count <= 1;
        end else begin
            count <= count + 1;
        end
    end
end

//other AXI stuff
endmodule
```

[image: block design]

In the AXI module, the 512*32bit logged data is mapped to addresses from 0x43c20000 to 0x43c20800.

In the Verilog code, the logger adds a new entry only when the boolean input flips. In simulation, the module works as expected. But in the FPGA, sometimes the logged data is not valid. There are successive 2 data and their MSB bit is the same, which means the entry is added even when the boolean input stays the same.

[image: logged data]

The invalid data appear from time to time. I've tried reading from the address programmatically (`*(u32*)(0x43c20000+4*idx)`), and there are still invalid data. I watch `idx` in a ILA module and `idx` is 512, which means the logging finishes when I read the data.

The FPGA clock is 10 MHz. The input signal is 10 Hz. So the typical period is 10e6/10/2=0x7A120, which most of the data is close to, except the invalid data.

I think if the Verilog code is implemented well, there should be no such invalid data. What may be the problem? Is this an issue about timing?

[The code](https://github.com/mjs225/BoolLogger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are you absolutely sure you are not issuing an accidental write on the AXI bus, resetting the registers?

If so, have you tried inserting a so-called double-flop on `data_in` (two flip-flops, delaying the signal two clock ticks)? I suppose that your `data_in` is not synchronous to the FPGA clock, which will lead to metastability and you having bad days if not accounted for. Have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027132112/https://www.nandland.com/articles/metastability-in-an-fpga.html) for information by NANDLAND.

Citing the linked source:

> If you have ever tried to sample some input to your FPGA, such as a button press, or if you have had to cross clock domains, you have had to deal with Metastability. A metastable state is one in which the output of a Flip-Flop inside of your FPGA is unknown, or non-deterministic. When a metastable condition occurs, there is no way to tell if the output of your Flip-Flop is going to be a 1 or a 0. A metastable condition occurs when setup or hold times are violated.
>
> **Metastability is bad.** It can cause your FPGA to exhibit very strange behavior.

In that source there is also a link to a white paper from Altera about the topic of metastability, linked [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401083656/https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01082-quartus-ii-metastability.pdf) for reference.

Citing from that paper:

> When a metastable signal does not resolve in the allotted time, a logic failure can result if the destination logic observes inconsistent logic states, that is, different destination registers capture different values for the metastable signal.

and

> To minimize the failures due to metastability in asynchronous signal transfers, circuit designers typically use a sequence of registers (a synchronization register chain or synchronizer) in the destination clock domain to resynchronize the signal to the new clock domain. These registers allow additional time for a potentially metastable signal to resolve to a known value before the signal is used in the rest of the design.

Basically having the asynchronous signal routed to two flip-flops might for example lead to one FF reading a 1 and one FF reading a 0. This in turn could lead to the data point being saved, but the counter not being reset to 0 (hence doubling the measured time) and the bit being saved as 0.

Finally, it seems to me, that you are using the Vivado-generated example AXI core. [Dan Gisselquist](https://web.archive.org/web/20220409013720/https://zipcpu.com/blog/2021/05/22/vhdlaxil.html) simply calls it "broken". This might not be the problem here, but you might want to have a look at his posts and his AXI core design.